# Spotlight plugin reading NSDocument causing "deny file-write-data" error in console

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument, appstore-sandbox, spotlight, spotlight-plugin

I have a sandboxed NSDocument based app with a Spotlight plugin to index my custom documents.

During testing I noticed a lot of errors being logged to the console by the Spotlight plugin as it indexes a document:

```
5/4/15 3:11:18.765 PM sandboxd[432]: ([579]) mdworker(579) deny file-write-data 
  /Users/test/Desktop/test.document 
  (import fstype:hfs fsflag:480D000 flags:240000005E diag:0 isXCode:0
    uti:com.test.document 
  plugin:/TestApp.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/TestApp Spotlight Importer.mdimporter - 
  find suspect file using: sudo mdutil -t 407144)
```

It appears as if the plugin attempts to write to the file it indexes (although it has only read-only access).

In my Spotlight plugin implementation I don't do anything in particular to write to the document. All I do is initialize my NSDocument subclass to read from the document:

```
[[TTCustomDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url ofType:contentType error:outError];
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9015ee92 __mac_syscall + 10
1   libsystem_sandbox.dylib         0x00007fff910140b0 sandbox_check + 206
2   AppKit                          0x00007fff8f75fc38 -[NSDocument _autosavingPossibilityConcern] + 213
3   AppKit                          0x00007fff8f75fb02 -[NSDocument _checkAutosavingPossibilityAndReturnError:] + 60
4   AppKit                          0x00007fff8f75f9cf -[NSDocument _checkAutosavingAndReturnError:] + 26
5   AppKit                          0x00007fff8f75f97e -[NSDocument _checkAutosavingAndUpdateLockedState] + 26
6   AppKit                          0x00007fff8f75e420 -[NSDocument _initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] + 319
7   AppKit                          0x00007fff8f75e056 -[NSDocument initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] + 230
```

Looks like the autosaving check is somehow attempting to write to the document.

Is there anything I can do about this? Is there some sort of read-only mode to open an NSDocument?

*Update:*

To reproduce:

1. Create a new Xcode project: "Cocoa document based app"
2. Add a Spotlight plugin
3. Code for the NSDocument implementation and Spotlight plugin are here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c4929586dfa11a473673

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so where's the code for `-[TTCustomDocument initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:]` or any other custom initialization code, as well as your `-readFromURL:ofType:error` and related code? It's likely you're triggering something from one of these (init... and/or read...) methods that causes the document to be flagged as dirty (having unsaved changes), which results in the autosave system being triggered. This is improper behavior in your `TTCustomDocument` class.

My guess is you're triggering something that registered a change with the document's undo manager. Easy to do if it's a Core Data document and you're setting up some initial data; also easy to do if you set up initial data in a way that calls one of your own undo-aware funnel methods. The easiest work-around (recommended by the documentation) is to call `[self.undoManager disableUndoRegistration];` before the changes and `[self.undoManager enableUndoRegistration]; after the changes and before returning self.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I did not override `initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:`. In `init` I set up some internal objects. I do use `[self.undoManager disableUndoRegistration]` when reading the contents. Looking at the stack trace, I think it's checking right away if the document can be autosaved. I overrode `+ (BOOL)autosavesInPlace` to return YES.

Comment: I reproduced this with a sample app based on the Xcode document app template. The problem only occurs if `autosavesInPlace` returns YES. I'm going to file a bug report to see what they say at Apple about this.

Comment: What internal objects? How do you set them up? These are critical details.

Comment: I added a gist with the relevant code to the question.